# How do I sum the second value in a data frame that is made of tuples and use the output to create a new column in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming, tuples

I have a data frame with 6 columns and 3 rows. The data frame is made of tuples e.g `(3, 5)(4, 5)(3, 5)(5, 5)(2, 3)(5, 3)`.

I need to create a function that adds the second number of tuples that start with the same first number in the row e.g `(3, 5)` will correspond with `(3,5)` then we add both fives which gives us 10 and save the total to a new column in the same data frame.

[This is what my data frame looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plyKf.png)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Ah I see. So you need a sum across all columns, but what is the exact criterium for adding them. Do you add all tuples with three in their first element. What about the fives in your example (5,3)(5,5)?

Comment: @jottbe After adding all the tuples that start with a three the outcome should be 10 in a new column in my existing data frame, after adding all tuples in the column that start with five the out come should be 8 in a new column in the same row of the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to filter on certain values for the first element. You can do it as this:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({
        'tuple1': [(3,1), (4,3), (2,2), (3,1)], 
        'tuple2': [(4,1), (1,1), (2,1), (5,2)],
        'tuple3': [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,5)],
        'tuple4': [(3,4), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1)],
        'tuple5': [(4,2), (1,2), (3,1), (5,4)],
        })

def sum_tuples(df, tup_columns, sum_column, filter_value):
    df[sum_column]= 0
    for col in tup_columns:
        df[sum_column]+= df[col].map(lambda t: t[1] if t[0] == filter_value else 0)

sum_tuples(df, ['tuple1', 'tuple2', 'tuple3', 'tuple4', 'tuple5'], 'sum_threes', 3)
```

It checks all tuples in the columns passed as a list (tuple1, ...) and sums all 2nd components of those with a certain value (3 in the example) and stores the result in the specified result column of the frame (sum_threes in the example). The result is 5, 0, 5, 2.

If you instead want to sum up all tuples according to their first value, without having to call the function several times, you can do it as follows:

```
# define a function that handles the tuples of a row
# and outputs the sum for all tuples whose first component 
# occured more than once
def agg_tuples(tuples):
    d= dict()
    multiple= set()
    for k, v in tuples:
        if k in d:
            # the first component already occured before
            # for this row --> memorize this in multiple
            d[k]+= v
            multiple.add(k)
        else:
            # value k occured the first time
            d[k]= v
    # now only return the sums of the tuples that occured multiple times
    return [(k, d[k]) for k in multiple]

# prepare an auxillary series with all tuple columns in one list
lists= df.apply(lambda r: agg_tuples([r[col] for col in ['tuple1', 'tuple2', 'tuple3', 'tuple4', 'tuple5']]), axis='columns')

# the following line would be the number of colums we 
# need at least to store all the result tuples
mx= max(lists.map(len))
# now we just need to split the list into seperate columns
# therefore we define three columns
result_cols= ['res1', 'res2', 'res3']
for idx, col in enumerate(result_cols):
    df[col]= lists.map(lambda l: l[idx] if idx<len(l) else None)
```

Comment: I updated my proposal. It sums the 2nd component per row in all columns that have a certain number in the 1st component. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for now I just have to make it work on my data frame with 1555 rows and 50 columns.

Comment: You are welcome. I think you won't run into performance issues with a data frame of such a size.

Comment: I would like to ask, if my data frame has tuples that aren't passed in as a list how might I get the function to work because right now it is giving me 0's in the new column that is created